# Difference of two dates using C++

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to take the difference of two dates by first reading the local time saving the tm structure and going to sleep for 5 seconds and read another local time and saving to another tm structure. I was hoping once I take the differences of the two dates to get a value 5 or greater. However, I am getting 0.

I get the correct result if comment out the following lines:

```
  oldyear.tm_year = oldyear.tm_year + 1900;
  oldyear.tm_mon = oldyear.tm_mon + 1;


  newyear.tm_year = newyear.tm_year + 1900;
  newyear.tm_mon = newyear.tm_mon + 1;
```

My code:

```
void timeTest()
{

  time_t now;
  struct tm newyear, oldyear;
  double seconds;

  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */
  oldyear = *localtime(&now);
  oldyear.tm_year = oldyear.tm_year + 1900;
  oldyear.tm_mon = oldyear.tm_mon + 1;

  int epoch1 = mktime(&oldyear);
  sleep(5);
  time(&now);  /* get current time; same as: now = time(NULL)  */

  newyear = *localtime(&now);
 newyear.tm_year = newyear.tm_year + 1900;
  newyear.tm_mon = newyear.tm_mon + 1;

  int epoch2 = mktime(&newyear);

  seconds = difftime(mktime(&newyear),mktime(&oldyear));

  printf ("%.f seconds since new year in the current timezone.\n", seconds);
}
```

Comment: Why both c and c++ tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I compile this on Linux, a 64-bit system, I get the output

```
5 seconds since new year in the current timezone.
```

However, if I compile for 32-bit system,

```
% gcc -m32 test2.c
% ./a.out
0 seconds since new year in the current timezone.
```

Note that `mktime` expects that the year is 1900-based and month 0-based, so the adjustment you do is incorrect and might cause overflow on 32-bit computers. What your code does is calculate the difference of 2 points of time on date **3914-08-28** - on 32-bit systems the `time_t` usually is 32 bits, and the largest date representable is [03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19 January 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) aka **Y2K38** jf signed `time_t` is used.

On errors -1 is returned:

> If the specified broken-down time cannot be represented as calendar
>   time (seconds since the Epoch), `mktime()` returns `(time_t) -1` and does
>   not alter the members of the broken-down time structure.

Thus if you print out `epoch` and `epoch2` I could bet you get `-1` for both these timestamps.

Comment: Antit, Thanks for your tip. The Target device has QNX OS and It's 32 bit. When I print Epoch1 and Epoch2, I get both -1. If I do not do that adjustment, will I get the correct date? If I omit  oldyear.tm_year = oldyear.tm_year + 1900;
  oldyear.tm_mon = oldyear.tm_mon + 1;

  newyear.tm_year = newyear.tm_year + 1900;
  newyear.tm_mon = newyear.tm_mon + 1; Will I get the correct date?

Comment: Yes, you will get the correct date. Given valid `time_t t`, `t` should be equal to `mktime(localtime(t))`

Comment: And if you believe that your question was answered then please do tick this answer as accepted.